# Angular, "activate" a watch after data has come in

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to have a $watch on a scope so I Can listen for changes, however, I do not want the watch to start listening until the data has come in and populated. I am using a $q factory and then to populate the items, then I want the watch to start listening after everything is populated. I can't seem to get down how to control these order of events.

SO I have  in my controller -

```
//call to the $q factoy to execut all http calls
getDefaults.resource.then(function(data){
    //fill in scopes with data
    $scope.allAccounts = data[0].data.accounts;

    //THEN watch the scope for changes
    $scope.$watch('selectedResources', function (newValue) { 
        //do action on change here
    });
}
```

SO I'm wondering if there is any way to control these order of events in angular. Thanks for reading!

Comment: The above code looks right, what's it not doing?

Comment: Try adding the watch inside a $timeout

Comment: I'd prefer not to use a timeout as I cannot guarantee how long the http requests will take.

Comment: Is getDefaults.resource a promise that is the thing doing the http calls to retrieve and populate data?  If so then it looks like it should work. Posting a bit more code that shows us what is going on to set getDefaults.resource might be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a service for your xhr calls:

```
.factory('xhrService', function ($http) {
    return {
        getData: function () {
             return $http.get('/your/url').then(cb);
        }
    };

    function cb(data) {
       /// process data if you need
       return data.accounts;
    }
});
```

after that you can use it like this inside your controller:

```
.controller('myController', function (xhrService) {
    $scope.allAccounts = [];

    xhrService.getData()
        .then(function (accounts) {
            $scope.allAccounts = accounts;
            return $scope.allAccounts;
        })
        .then(function () {
           $scope.$watch('allAccounts', function (newValue) {
              // do something
           } 
        });
});
```

I think this is a good way to structure your code because you can reuse your service and you can add (or not) any watch you need (inside any controller)

And the most important, from the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q - "$q.then method returns a **new promise** which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the successCallback, errorCallback" - this is why each `then callback` needs a return statement.